# Add a image to a post published on a CPT from the front-end

Tags: custom-post-types, front-end, wp-insert-post

I created a CPT with a page where you can add posts from the Frontend.
This is the code in the fuction.php:

```
// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_promociona', 0 );

if ( ! function_exists('register_cpt_promociona') ) {

    // Register Custom Post Type
    function register_cpt_promociona() {

        $labels = array(
            'name'                => _x( 'Promociones publicadas', 'Post Type General Name', 'ainder' ),
            'singular_name'       => _x( 'Promociona', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'ainder' ),
            'menu_name'           => __( 'Promociona', 'ainder' ),
            'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Promoción padre', 'ainder' ),
            'all_items'           => __( 'Todas las Promociones', 'ainder' ),
            'view_item'           => __( 'Ver Promociones', 'ainder' ),
            'add_new_item'        => __( 'Tu Promoción', 'ainder' ),
            'add_new'             => __( 'Añadir nuevo', 'ainder' ),
            'edit_item'           => __( 'Editar Promoción', 'ainder' ),
            'update_item'         => __( 'Actualizar Promoción', 'ainder' ),
            'search_items'        => __( 'Buscar Promoción', 'ainder' ),
            'not_found'           => __( 'Ningna Promoción encontrada', 'ainder' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Ningna Promoción encontrada en la papelera', 'ainder' ),
        );

        $rewrite = array(
            'slug'                => 'promociona',
            'with_front'          => true,
            'pages'               => true,
            'feeds'               => true,
        );

        $args = array(
            'label'               => __( 'promociona', 'ainder' ),
            'description'         => __( 'CPT de Promociones de usuarios', 'ainder' ),
            'labels'              => $labels,
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'comments', 'custom-fields', ),
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'categoria-promociona' ),
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 5,
            'can_export'          => true,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
        );

        register_post_type( 'promociona', $args );

    } // end function register_cpt_promociona

} // end if (!function_exists)

// Lo enganchamos en la acción init y llamamos a la función create_promociona_taxonomies() cuando arranque
add_action( 'init', 'create_promociona_taxonomies', 0 );

// Creamos dos taxonomías, género y autor para el custom post type "promoción"
function create_promociona_taxonomies() {
    // Añadimos nueva taxonomía y la hacemos jerárquica (como las categorías por defecto)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categoría de la promoción', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Categoría promociona', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      =>  __( 'Buscar por Categoría' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'Todas las Categorías' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Categoría padre' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Categoría padre:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Editar Categoría' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Actualizar Categoría' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Añadir nueva Categoría' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'Nombre de la nueva Categoría' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'categoria-promociona', 
        array( 'promociona' ), 
            array(
                'hierarchical'  => true,
                'labels'        => $labels, /* ADVERTENCIA: Aquí es donde se utiliza la variable $labels */
                'show_ui'       => true,
                'query_var'     => true,
                'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'categoria-promociona' ),
            )
        );
} // end function create_promociona_taxonomies
```

And this is the code in the file page-proyecta.php:

```
    <?php

/**
 * Template Name: AINDER Promociona Loop
 *
 * @package BuddyPress
 * @subpackage Theme
 */

if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
}

get_header( 'buddypress' ); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#titulo-cpt').focus(function(event) { 
            jQuery('#whats-new-options').addClass('whats-new-options-open', 2000);
        });
        jQuery('#whats-new').focus(function(event) {
            jQuery('#whats-new-options').addClass('whats-new-options-open', 2000);
        });
    });
</script>

<?php 
    // Conseguimos primero el id de la página para la imagen destacada y lo guardamos en una variable
    $id_page = get_the_ID();
    // Conseguimos el objeto ainder-promociona (CPT)
    $obj = get_post_type_object( 'promociona' );
?>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="item-header" role="complementary">

            <div id="item-header-avatar">

                <div class="single-group-box-image-container">
                    <a href="" title="<?php echo $obj->labels->singular_name; ?>"><img src="http://localhost/ainder/wp-content/uploads/group-avatars/30/aacdd8a094d297fd5d336809ccd89d01-bpfull.jpg" class="avatar group-30-avatar avatar-150 photo" width="150" height="150" alt="Logo del grupo LA INTELIGENCIA EMOCIONAL EN EL EMPRENDEDOR"></a>
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id_page, array( 150, 150 ) ); ?>
                </div>

            </div><!-- #item-header-avatar -->

            <div id="item-header-content" class="cpt-morado">

                <h2><?php echo $obj->labels->singular_name; ?></h2>

                <div class="single-group-meta"></div>

                    <p><?php _e( '¿Tienes una empresa, organización u ONG? <br>
                    Dala a conocer', 'ainder' ); ?></p>

                    <div class="gtags-header"><!-- Categorías -->
                    </div> <!-- .gtags-header -->

            </div><!-- #item-header-content -->
        </div><!-- #item-header -->


        <div id="item-body">

<!-- FORMULARIO -->

            <?php
            // Para crear los post desde el front con un formulario
            if ($_POST && ( $_POST['titulo-promociona'] != '' ) ) {

                $post_type      = 'promociona';
                $post_title     = $_POST['titulo-promociona'];
                $post_content   = $_POST['contenido-promociona'];
                $post_category  = $_POST['categoria-promociona'];
                $image          = $_POST['imagen-promociona'];
                $video_url      = $_POST['video-promociona'];
                $enlace_url     = $_POST['enlace-promociona'];

                $new_post = array(
                 'post_author'      => $user->ID,
                 'post_title'       => $post_title,
                 'post_content'     => $post_content,
                 'post_category'    => array($post_category),
                 'post_status'      => 'publish',
                 'comment_status'   => 'open',
                 'post_type'        => $post_type
                );

                // Creamos el post con los datos de $new_post y obtenemos su ID nuevecita
                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );

                // Insertamos la "categoría" (realmente es una taxonomía)
                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $post_category, 'categoria-promociona');

                if ( !empty( $video_url )  ) {
                    // Insertamos en DDBB la URL del video si lo hay
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'video_url', $video_url );
                }

                if ( !empty( $enlace_url ) ) {
                    // Insertamos en DDBB la URL del enlace si lo hay
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'enlace_url', $enlace_url );
                }


                // Para la imagen lo tenemos un poco más complicado
                if ( !empty( $image ) ) {
                    // Guardamos la ruta del directorio upload en una variable
                    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                    // Leemos el archivo y lo guardamos en una variable
                    $image_data = file_get_contents($image);
                    // Nombramos la imagen con el nombre del archivo
                    $filename   = basename($image);

                    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
                        $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
                    else
                        $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;

                    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

                    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );

                    $attachment = array(
                        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                        'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name($filename),
                        'post_content'   => '',
                        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                    );

                    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

                    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

                    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

                    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
                } // end if (isset($image))

            } // end if ($_POST)
            ?>

            <div class="cpt-title">
                <h4><?php echo $obj->labels->add_new_item; ?></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="cpt_form_container">

                <form action="" method="post" id="whats-new-form" name="whats-new-form" >

                    <?php // do_action( 'bp_before_activity_post_form' ); ?>

                    <div id="whats-new-avatar"> <!-- AVATAR DEL USUARIO -->
                        <a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain(); ?>">
                            <?php bp_loggedin_user_avatar( 'width=' . bp_core_avatar_thumb_width() . '&height=' . bp_core_avatar_thumb_height() ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <p class="titulo-cpt">
                        <?php _e( 'Titula tu Link', 'ainder' ); ?>
                    </p>

                    <div id="whats-new-content">

                        <div id="whats-new-textarea">
                                <input type="text" class="bp-suggestions" name="titulo-promociona" id="titulo-cpt" required maxlength="60"></input>
                        </div>

                        <p class="input-cpt">
                            <?php printf( __( '%s, explica en qué consiste y qué ofreces (max. 300 caracteres)', 'ainder' ), bp_get_user_firstname( bp_get_loggedin_user_fullname() ) ); ?>
                        </p>

                        <div id="whats-new-textarea">
                            <textarea class="bp-suggestions" name="contenido-promociona" id="whats-new" required>
                            </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div id="whats-new-options">
                            <p class="input-cpt">
                                <?php _e( 'Añade una imagen (obligatorio)', 'ainder' ); ?>
                            </p>
                            <div id="whats-new-textarea">
                                <input type="file" class="bp-suggestions" name="imagen-promociona" id="imagen-cpt" required>
                            </div>

                            <p class="input-cpt">
                                <?php _e( 'Añade el Link', 'ainder' ); ?>
                            </p>
                            <div id="whats-new-textarea">
                                <input type="url" class="bp-suggestions" name="enlace-promociona" id="enlace-cpt">
                            </div>

                            <p class="input-cpt">
                                <?php _e( 'Añade un video', 'ainder' ); ?>
                            </p>
                            <div id="whats-new-textarea">
                                <input type="url" class="bp-suggestions" title="Si pegas el enlace para compartir de Youtube, aparecerá el vídeo, si sólo pegas la ruta normal aparecerá el enlace vinculado al vídeo" name="video-promociona" id="video-cpt">
                            </div>

                            <div id="whats-new-submit">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Publicar', 'ainder' ); ?>" />
                            </div>

                            <?php //if ( bp_is_active( 'groups' ) && !bp_is_my_profile() && !bp_is_group() ) : ?>

                            <div id="whats-new-post-in-box">

                                <?php _e( 'Publicar en', 'ainder' ); ?>:

                                <select required id="whats-new-post-in" name="categoria-promociona">
                                    <option selected="selected" value="">
                                        <?php 
                                            $args = array(
                                                'post_type' => 'promociona',
                                                'taxonomy'  => 'categoria-promociona',
                                                'hide_empty' => 0,
                                                'order' => 'ASC'
                                            );

                                            $categories = get_categories($args);

                                            foreach($categories as $category) { 
                                                                //echo '<div class="cat"><h2><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "have a look at %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></h2><br /><p>Books: '. $category->count.' </p></div> '; 
                                                echo "<option value='".$category->name."'>$category->name</option>"; // $category->term_id
                                            }  
                                        ?>

                                </select>
                            </div> <!-- #whats-new-post-in-box -->
                                <!-- <input type="hidden" id="whats-new-post-object" name="whats-new-post-object" value="groups" /> -->

                            <?php // elseif ( bp_is_group_home() ) : ?>

                                <!-- <input type="hidden" id="whats-new-post-object" name="whats-new-post-object" value="groups" /> -->
                                <!-- <input type="hidden" id="whats-new-post-in" name="whats-new-post-in" value="<?php// bp_group_id(); ?>" /> -->

                            <?php // endif; ?>

                            <?php //do_action( 'bp_activity_post_form_options' ); ?>

                        </div><!-- #whats-new-options -->
                    </div><!-- #whats-new-content -->

                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'post_update', '_wpnonce_post_update' ); ?>
                    <?php// do_action( 'bp_after_activity_post_form' ); ?>

                </form><!-- #whats-new-form -->
            </div> <!-- .bpfb_form_container -->
        </div> <!-- .item-body -->

<!-- /FORMULARIO -->

<!-- Loop de CPT promociona -->

        <div class="titulo-loop">
            <h4><?php echo $obj->labels->name; ?></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="categoria-loop">
            <div id="titulo-desplegable">
                <span class="desplegable"><?php _e('Elegir por categorías', 'ainder') ?></span>


                <!-- <option selected="selected" value="0"><?php _e("Elegir categoría", "ainder"); ?></option> -->
                <?php 
                $terms = get_terms( 'categoria-promociona' );

                echo '<ul class="desplegable-categoria-loop">';


                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
                    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

                    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
                    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
                    echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
                }

                echo '</ul>';


                ?>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .categoria-loop -->

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div id="item-loop">

            <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $wp_query  = new WP_Query( array( 
                'post_type'             => 'promociona',
                'post-category'         => array( $category_name ),
                'posts_per_page'        => 7,
                'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
                'paged'                 => $paged
                )
            );

        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="cpindex">

            <div class="cpautor">

                <span class="avatar">
                    <a href="<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>" title="<?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?>">
                        <?php bp_activity_avatar( array( 'user_id' => get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span class="texto-publicado"><?php _e('Publicado por: ', 'ainder'); ?></span>
            </div> <!-- .cpautor -->

            <div class="cpthumbnail">
                <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array( 100, 100) );
                 } ?>
            </div>

            <div class="cptitle">
                <h5><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h5>
            </div>

            <div class="cpcategories">

                <p class="custompostmetadata"><?php _e( 'CATEGORÍA:', 'ainder'); ?> <?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'categoria-promociona' ); ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="cpcontent">

                <?php the_excerpt(); ?> <?php //the_content(); ?>
                <div class="cpmetas">

                    <span class="cplink"><?php _e( 'Link: ', 'ainder'); ?><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'enlace_url', true ); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'enlace_url', true ); ?></a></span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="cpvideo"><?php _e( 'Video: ', 'ainder'); ?><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_url', true ); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_url', true ); ?></a></span> 
                </div> <!-- .cpmetas -->
            </div> <!-- .cpcontent -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div> <!-- .cpindex -->

    <?php endwhile;

    if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { ?>
        <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
            Paginación
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Anteriores', 'ainder' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Siguientes <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'ainder' ) ); ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php } // end if($loop-)
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

        </div>

    </div><!-- .content -->

<?php get_sidebar( 'buddypress' ); ?>
<?php get_footer( 'buddypress' ); ?>
```

## Where the important point is this:

```
    // Para la imagen lo tenemos un poco más complicado
if ( !empty( $image ) ) {
    // Guardamos la ruta del directorio upload en una variable
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    // Leemos el archivo y lo guardamos en una variable
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image);
    // Nombramos la imagen con el nombre del archivo
    $filename   = basename($image);

    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
        $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else
        $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;

    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );

    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
} // end if (isset($image))
```

The problem is that, even though the picture is in the gallery of media, it does not look anywhere.
I think it has to do with the time of reading the image file (`$ image_data = file_get_contents ($ image);`) or by inserting data file (`file_put_contents ($ file, $ image_data);`).
Can anyone shed some light on the matter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After two days looking for the solution and fighting with the code, **I found the solution**:

As I suspected, the problem was reading the file (`$image_data = file_get_contents($image);`).

The first error was not included in the form `enctype =" multipart / form-data "` to send files and data simultaneously.

The second error was that images are not loaded by $_POST, if not the global variable $_FILES  (In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead of $_FILES).

And the last error was that we have to move the file to the directory uploads to read it from there with `move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['imagen-promociona']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile )`

I hope at least help others.

Thanks